# Maven asks to check ant jar is intact

Tags: maven, ant, clover

I'm having an issue with maven and ant. I'm pulling jars from a repo to my computer and have all the jars required on the repo and refs added to the pom file. When I try to run clover2:setup I get an error

```
Downloading: http://remoteRepo/nexus/content/groups/xxxx/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.4/ant-1.8.4.jar
1896K downloaded  (ant-1.8.4.jar)
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------    ---
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------    ---
[INFO] The plugin descriptor for the plugin Plugin [org.apache.ant:ant] was not
found. Please verify that the plugin JAR     C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\localrepo\or
g\apache\ant\ant\1.8.4\ant-1.8.4.jar is intact.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The plugin descriptor for the plugin Plugin [or
g.apache.ant:ant] was not found. Please verify that the plugin JAR C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\localrepo\org\apache\ant\ant\1.8.4\ant-1.8.4.jar is intact.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginM
anager.java:360)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyVersionedPlugin(De
faultPluginManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPlug
inManager.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDescriptor(Def
aultPluginManager.java:1642)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:1540)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor
(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1787)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.segmentTaskListBy
AggregationNeeds(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
fecycleExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:6
0)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 28 05:37:02 CDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've extracted the jar file and checked the Manifest.MF file and it's pom and the ref in my pom are the same.

What reasons would there be for a jar not to be considered intact?

Remote repo in the URL is just to hide where the actual URL points to but left in to show it's pulling jars and is not a proxy issue. Also I've cleared the local repo many times

Comment: Can you show us your pom ? Why are you using Ant 1.8.4 instead of the latest release for example ?

Comment: I can't, it's a work thing and the pom is huge. I'm using 1.8.4 as maven-clover2-plugin uses it

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.maven.plugins/maven-clover2-plugin/3.3.0

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.ant:ant` is very unlikely to be a Maven plugin. Check your pom.xml for incorrect plugin declarations.

Comment: thanks, if it's not a plugin do you know what tag it might fall under?

Comment: `dependency` is a good start. But it is better to create a minimal pom file which reproduces the problem and post it here.